# How can I import a 3D graph to the Unity interface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, virtual-reality

Running into a bit of trouble with a program that can create a 3D graph on Unity after inputting an xyz function into a basic C# UI. (format is z= function in terms of x and y)

Things I've tried are having the OBJ fetched from the Wolfram Alpha API to download into the Assets folder of the project, but this doesn't seem to be public or accessible at the moment. Another is finding some way to graph a 3D graph in the Unity program by creating a C+ script and attach it to an empty object that would generate the graph, but such a function seems almost impossible to create.

This is my first independent program, and I'm probably most definitely going beyond the extent of my ability, but perhaps there's a simple way to do this? What appealed me was that the manual steps to getting the 3D graph onto Unity are very simple, but creating a program that can tie them all together is the biggest issue because fetching the OBJ from Wolfram Alpha seems impossible.

The 3-D graphs I'm aiming for are the kind generated from a MATLAB or WolframAlpha input.

Comment: You may want to proof your question a bit to increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick is to use Unity's [Terrain Engine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Terrain.html?_ga=1.203372818.2034199442.1488265080) in combination with heightmaps to achieve you goal. Basically export a heightmap from your matlab code (z between 0 and 1 in terms of y and x) and add it to your Terrain object, and it will look like your 3d function.

The nice way to do it so it is entirely self contained in unity would be to create a mesh from a given set of points. You can create a plane and displace each of the vertices to their calculated z position. If you are completely lost on what I am saying and would like to learn some interesting Unity stuff [this video serie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpB4BApnKhM)s by Quill18 helps with most of what you need.

Good Luck!